# Graph API returns Authorization_IdentityNotFound error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

We are using `GET /v1.0/users/${email}` API to fetch the user details in a tenant and getting the following error in the response.

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
      "innerError":{
         "client-request-id":"a1fdaeb3-775d-47ba-8be3-27ce3a134a77",
         "date":"2023-03-15T12:53:29",
         "request-id":"a1fdaeb3-775d-47ba-8be3-27ce3a134a77"
      },
      "message":"The identity of the calling application could not be established."
   }
}
```

The app asks for `User.Read.All` **Application** type scope and using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint to get the token via admin consent. All this was setup using [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

We have checked that the app has given scope permission successfully in Azure portal by an admin of tenant

[Permission given to App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvEfN.png)

Went throught existing questions on Stackoverflow and Microsoft support page. All answer point to app not given permission successfully but that is not the case for us.

We were thinking if it is possible to check more error details for `request-id: a1fdaeb3-775d-47ba-8be3-27ce3a134a77` on Microsoft side? Or some other steps that can help us in debugging and finding the casue for the error

Comment: How do you call the endpoint (ie. PowerShell, Postman, etc.)?

Comment: @user2250152 we are calling it via Axios from our service which is in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get your access token using this endpoint

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`

You have to use your own domain instead of `common`

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourdomain.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`

or you can also use your tenant id

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but we are already using `tenantid` and not `common` in the `/oauth2/v2.0/token` API

Comment: @ShubhamTanwar I see. I'm afraid the only scenario I can replicate this error message is a different tenant in access token endpoint.